# Make Jenkins plot a variable number of files

Tags: jenkins

I have a Python script that I run in Jenkins. At the end of that script, each time the job is built, some number of *.csv files are created, which need to be plotted separately. I know how to plot a single file in Jenkins, but the issue is that I don't know how to plot multiple files at the same time and on different plots.

What I've tried so far is copying all the required files to the job workspace. I'm not providing the Python script and the batch commands used for the job, because they're irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Could you please specify what plugin you are using to plot a single csv file?

Comment: @smelm I guess it's the default one.

Comment: so what command do you use to plot something? And do you use a pipeline or freestyle job?

Comment: @smelm I use a freestyle job, the plotting is done using one of the Post-Build actions, Plot Build Data.